# Python: How to block in PyGTK while waiting for timeout_add callback?

Tags: python, pygtk, glib, pygobject, gtk2

I need to convert a synchronous function in a PyGTK application to use an asynchronous library.

The library uses `timeout_add` and `io_add_watch` with callbacks (see example below). It does *not* use python threads, so the python `threading` library would not work.

Is there something like `threading.Event` in PyGTK/ GLib that would allow me to block inside the function until the asynchronous library calls the callback with the return data?

**Old function:**

```
def sync_fetch():
    return 'The Result'
```

**Asynchronous library example:**

```
def async_fetch(callback):
    assert callable(callback)
    gobject.timeout_add(100, lambda: callback('The Result'))
```

**Possible structure**: (using something like `threading.Event`)

```
class AsyncToSyncFetch(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._event = Event()
        self._result = None

    def _set_result(self, result):
        self._result = result
        self._event.set()

    def sync_fetch(self):
        async_fetch(callback=self._set_result)
        # block here until _event.set() is called
        self._event.wait()
        return self._result
```

**I put a small GTK test program here** (using `threading.Event`, which times out): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/206d1cc7218994e620a7#file-gtk_async_to_sync-py

**Update - possible solution:** I found a solution using nested main loops in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18021740/2038464). But this can only be used in one area at a time in a main loop, since the "unblock" function is global and not specifically matched to the "block" function. From [gtk_main](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html#gtk-main): "gtk_main_quit() will make the innermost invocation of the main loop return."

```
    def sync_fetch(self):
        # start the async function first
        async_fetch(callback=self._result_loaded)
        # nest another mainloop, which blocks
        # until gtk.main_quit() is called
        gtk.main()
        # this will get loaded before we resume
        return self._result

    # this is the callback from the async function
    def _result_loaded(self, result):
        print('result loaded')
        # it saves a variable accessible from sync_fetch
        self._result = result
        # exit the nested main loop, allowing sync_fetch to resume
        gtk.main_quit()
```

Comment: As far as I remember, you should just use normal language constructs for interthread communication.

Comment: Python's `threading` library does not work because GLib uses its own type of threading. Any blocks put in by the `threading` library (except inside a new python thread) block the entire main loop, including the event sources.